# How many points $M\in(S)$ are there such that tangent plane $(P_M)$ intersects $Ox$ and $Oy$ at positive integer points and $\angle{AMB}=90^\circ$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> In a three-dimensional Cartesian coordinates system $Oxyz$, consider sphere $(S)\colon (x - 2)^2 + (y - 3)^2 + (z - 1)^2 = 1$. How many points $M$ which lie on $(S)$ are there such that the tangent plane to sphere $(S)$ at point $M$ intersects axes $Ox$ and $Oy$ at points $A (a; 0; 0)$ and $B (0; b; 0)$ respectively where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and $\angle{AMB} = 90^\circ$?

[For context, this question is taken from an exam whose format consists of 50 multiple-choice questions with a time limit of 90 minutes. Calculators are the only electronic device allowed in the testing room. (You know those scientific calculators sold at stationery stores and sometimes bookstores? They are the goods.) I need a solution that works within these constraints. Thanks for your cooperation, as always. (Do I need to sound this professional?)

By the way, if the wording of the problem sounds rough, sorry for that. I'm not an expert at translating documents.]

I tried to squeeze in as much information as possible in the title...

I've also just looked back at how I asked questions back then. I forbid you from looking at them (of course I can't actually prohibit you from doing that, **BUT DON'T LOOK AT THEM~**)

I suppose one way to look at this is to consider the equation of sphere $(S')$ with diameter $AB$. It'd be $$\left(x - \dfrac{a}{2}\right)^2 + \left(y - \dfrac{b}{2}\right)^2 + z^2 = \left(\dfrac{a}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{b}{2}\right)^2 \iff x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - ax - by = 0$$

This is only an assumption, however, I suspect that $(S)$ and $(S')$ are tangent to each other.

Subtracting the equation of sphere $(S')$ from the equation of sphere $(S) \colon x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 4x - 6y - 2z + 13 = 0$, and we have that $(a - 4)x + (b - 6)y - 2z + 13 = 0$.

The intersection of plane $(P_M) \colon (a - 4)x + (b - 6)y - 2z + 13 = 0$ and line $d$ with the equation $\dfrac{x - 2}{a - 4} = \dfrac{y - 3}{b - 6} = \dfrac{z - 1}{-2}$ (basically the line connecting the centres of $(S)$ and $(S')$) is $M = $ $$\left(\dfrac{(a - 4)(15 - 2a - 3b)}{a^2 + b^2 - 8a - 12b + 56} + 2; \dfrac{(b - 6)(15 - 2a - 3b)}{a^2 + b^2 - 8a - 12b + 56} + 3; \dfrac{2(15 - 2a - 3b)}{a^2 + b^2 - 8a - 12b + 56} + 1\right)$$

Huh, and what's next? (◑ ○◑)

How about this? Suppose the coordinates of $M$ are $(m, n, p) \ (1 \le m \le 3, 2 \le n \le 4, 0 \le p \le 2)$. The equation of the tangent plane to sphere $S$ at point $M$ is $(P_M)$ is $$(m - 2)(x - 2) + (n - 3)(y - 3) + (p - 1)(z - 1) = 1$$

And thereby, $\left\{ \begin{aligned} a &= \dfrac{3(n - 3) + (p - 1) + 1}{m - 2} + 2 = \dfrac{2m + 3n + p - 13}{m - 2}\\ b &= \dfrac{2(m - 2) + (p - 1) + 1}{n - 3} + 3 = \dfrac{2m + 3n + p - 13}{n - 3} \end{aligned} \right.$.

Furthermore, since $\angle{AMB} = 90^{\circ} \iff \overrightarrow{MA} \cdot \overrightarrow{MB} = 0$, it can be implied that $$\begin{aligned} m(m - a) + n(n - b) = 0 &\iff m \times \left(m - \dfrac{2m + 3n + p - 13}{m - 2}\right) + n \times \left(n - \dfrac{2m + 3n + p - 13}{n - 3}\right) = 0\\ &\iff (m^2 + n^2) - \left(\dfrac{m}{m - 2} + \dfrac{n}{n - 3}\right) \times (2m + 3n + p - 13) = 0\\ &\iff 2m + 3n + p - 13 = \dfrac{(m - 2)(n - 3)(m^2 + n^2)}{2mn - 3m - 2n} \end{aligned}$$, which means $\left\{ \begin{aligned} a &= \dfrac{(n - 3)(m^2 + n^2)}{2mn - 3m - 2n}\\ b &= \dfrac{(m - 2)(m^2 + n^2)}{2mn - 3m - 2n} \end{aligned} \right.$. Now we just need to find $m \in [1; 3]$ and $n \in [2; 4]$ such that both $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers.

$a$ and $b$ are both undefined when $2mn - 3m - 2n = 0 \implies n = \dfrac{3m}{2m - 2} \ (m \ne 1)$.

This is just a dumb experiment, but for $m = 1$, $\left\{ \begin{aligned} a &= \dfrac{(3 - n)(n^2 + 1)}{3} \in \left[-\dfrac{17}{3}; \dfrac{5}{3}\right], n \in [2; 4]\\ b &= \dfrac{n^2 + 1}{3} \end{aligned} \right.$.

For $a = 0$, $b$ is equal to $\dfrac{10}{3}$, and for $a = 1$, $b$ is equal to $\dfrac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$. So $m$ is definitely not $1$. But does that really matter?

By the way, the choices were $4, 1, 3$ and $2$. I'm banking on $2$ being the correct answer.

Comment: $\vec{MA}\cdot\vec{MB}=0 \Rightarrow$ $m(m-a)+n(n-b)+p^2=0 \Rightarrow$ $m(m-a)+n(n-b)=-p^2 \neq 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C(2;3;1)$ is center of $S$, $AM=c$, $BM=d$.
$$CM\perp AM, CM\perp BM, AM\perp BM \Rightarrow \\ AC^2=CM^2+AM^2, BC^2=CM^2+BM^2, AB^2=AM^2+BM^2 \Rightarrow \\ (a-2)^2+10=1+c^2,(b-3)^2+5=1+d^2,a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2\Rightarrow \\
a^2+b^2=(a-2)^2+(b-3)^2+13\Rightarrow \\
4a+6b=26 \Rightarrow 2a+3b=13\\
13 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow a\equiv 2\pmod 3 \\
2a < 13 \Rightarrow a\leq 6
a\equiv 2 \pmod 3, a\leq 6 \Rightarrow a=2 \lor a=5\\
b=\frac{13-2a}{3}\Rightarrow b=3 \lor b=1$$
Answer:$(a,b)=(2,3) \lor (a,b)=(5,1)$.

---

**Appendix 1**

It is still needed to find how many $M$ points correspond to one pair $(a,b)$.

$M$ is determined by $AM=c,BM=d,CM=1$. $AM=c$ and $BM=d$ determine circle which is intersection of two spheres. This circle is orthogonal to $AM$ which is tangent to $S$ then this circle is orthogonal to $S$, then this circle has two intersection points with $S$. Then every pair $(a,b)$ correspond to two points $M$. Then answer for original problem is 4.

---

**Appendix 2**

I'me made mistake in Appendix 1. One of intersection points in both cases is point $(2,3,0)$ which does not satisfy problem statement because tangent plane $z=0$ does not intersect but contains $Ox$ and $Oy$. Answer for original problem is 2 with $M_1(\frac{62}{49};\frac{123}{49};\frac{72}{49})$ and $M_2(\frac{158}{85};\frac{39}{17};\frac{144}{85})$.